# shell script to download files from remote machine using ftp

Tags: file, shell, ftp

I have

```
host name      :  "ftp.flowers.com" 
username       :  "name" 
password       :  "123" 
directory path :  "/flower/rose"
```

from which I have to download "red" file. the following script is not working

```
ftp -in ftp.flowers.com << SCRIPTEND
user name 123
binary
cd /flower/rose
mget red
SCRIPTEND
```

Answer (score 18):

It would be much simpler with `wget`:

```
wget ftp://name:123@ftp.flowers.com/flower/rose/red
```

Comment: does username and password disclosed over network if we use wget?

Comment: If by "disclosed" you mean "transmitted in clear text" or "not encrypted", then yes. But it's the same with the `ftp` command. This is a limitation of the protocol, not of the tool.

Comment: k..even if use ftp in shell script also it is transmitted in clear text??

Comment: Unfortunately... unless you're connecting through a VPN. However, there are alternative secured protocols like HTTPS or FTPS, but it must be supported by the server.

Comment: i am getting following error ...wget: unable to resolve host address

Comment: Can you `ping ftp.flowers.com` from the console ?

Comment: 64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=51 ttl=236 time=169 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=52 ttl=235 time=168 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=53 ttl=235 time=166 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=54 ttl=235 time=165 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=55 ttl=236 time=170 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=56 ttl=236 time=169 ms
64 bytes from ftp.kojamjoom.com (213.42.43.222): icmp_req=57 ttl=235 time=176 ms

Comment: this is the output am getting

Comment: Here: `wget ftp://ftp.kojamjoom.com` resolves the IP and connects to the server.

Comment: how to give username and password

Answer (score 4):

```
wget --user=name --password=123 ftp://ftp.flowers.com/flower/rose/red
```

To download to a different directory than the current directory:

```
wget --user=name --password=123 directory-prefix=/the/target/directory/ ftp://ftp.flowers.com/flower/rose/red
```

Then the files will be downloaded to `/the/target/directory/` .

If you know the name of the file ahead of time, you can use the -O option to wget to tell it where to write the file:

```
wget --user=name --password=123 --output-document=/the/target/directory/red ftp://ftp.flowers.com/flower/rose/red
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi all its already too late and you might have resolved your issue by now. But anyhow i would like to know if you have had resolved it with any other alternative method:

I've noticed minor change in this below script which you have given, well i guess it is the "/" which is you are missing after the location "cd /flower/rose"

```
ftp -in ftp.flowers.com << SCRIPTEND
user name 123
binary
cd /flower/rose/
mget red
SCRIPTEND
```